# Movable Type: Error running CRON

Tags: cron, movabletype

I have Movable Type 5.031 running on RHEL5.5
Im trying to run periodic tasks but I run into these errors.

```
root@sv cd /home/user/public_html/mt; ./tools/run-periodic-tasks
Out of memory (Needed 8160 bytes)
DBD::mysql::st execute warning:  at extlib/Data/ObjectDriver/Driver/DBI.pm line 153.
```

I have no idea what it is. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

What periodic tasks are you running? Just publishing posts in the que? It looks like the query result is too big for the memory available on the server.

Comment: Is there a config. I can change some where? my server has dedicated 4GB so running out of memory shouldn't be a problem.  I am just refreshing category archives periodically.

Comment: and also some index templates.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running the command as follows:

cd /home/user/public_html/mt; ./tools/run-periodic-tasks --verbose

This would probably provide you with more information about what's going on before the script runs out of memory.

Another thing that might be of help would be to turn on the [DebugMode](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/developer/turning-on-debug-mode.html).  Doing this would provide you with the line on which the script was failing.

Note that there are several possible settings for DebugMode that might expose other useful information.